# Decoding multiple JSON objects from stream

Tags: json, dart, json-deserialization

I am consuming a Stream that provides JSON-encoded objects which are separated by some whitespace, for example

```
{"id": 1} {"id": 2} {"id": 3}
```

The problem is, the JsonDecoder will stop after the first parsed Object. In fact, it will throw if there is more than one element:

```
  final inputs = ['{"id": 1} {"id": 2}'];
  final stream = Stream.fromIterable(inputs).transform(JsonDecoder());
  stream.listen((data) => print(data));
```

will give

> Unhandled exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at
>   character 11) {"id": 1} {"id": 2}

Is there a way to turn this `Stream<String>` decoded into a `Stream<Map>`?

I am using `json_serialize` later on as well, if this is any help.

Comment: I think you need to read through the string char-by-char and cut it on matching closing braces and then feed the parts into the JSON decoder.

Comment: Well, that would be unfortunate, as this means basically parsing everthing up front to get it right. And the provided decoder already emits the correct (first) object, so it *does* almost the complete work. :-/

Comment: https://github.com/llamadonica/dart-json-stream-parser might do what you want but it doesn't seem to be maintained since a long time.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think I might indeed end up with writing a basic JSON splitter...